# Can activity tags be included in activity reports or exports?

Tags: civireport, activities, reports, tags

tags have been added to a variety of activities by a user over the last few months.

Now they want to include the tag details in a report.

As far as I can see activity reports can filter by tag, but tey are not available as a column. And activity export does not give the option to include tags either.

Have I missed something? Anyone had any success getting this data out?

Civi 5.3.1

Comment: doesn't look like it is part of https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport either but could be a good place to get a change made to allow it